# Codeception functional test not running, but no error

Tags: laravel, virtual-machine, vagrant, functional-testing, codeception

I am following the *Build Larabook from scratch* Laracasts tutorial (building a Facebook-like app).

In lesson 14, we implement the "sign in" feature.

Problem, when I try to run my functional test (that has been running smoothly so far), I get nothing, not even an error message:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/larabook$ vendor/bin/codecept run functional
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.0.7
Powered by PHPUnit 4.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

Here is the content of my `SignInCept.php`:

```php
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->am('a Larabook member');
$I->wantTo('login to my Larabook account');

$I->signIn();

$I->seeInCurrentUrl('/statuses');
$I->see('Welcome back!');
```

I tried to log out of my Vagrant vm but kept getting the same issue.

Is it possible that I broke something while updating some files?

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully your signIn action in FunctionalHelper for any syntax errors. Tests fail like this without showing any errors when there is something wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but do not use composer exec. Use the full path to codeception.

For example:

```
**vendor/bin/codecept run**
```